# Sharepoint 2013 default save button in New form not working

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

In Sharepoint list New form  default save button is not working. On clicking on save even for  multiple times record is not saving. There is no required field error. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Any custom code (JS) on this page? Any console errors?

Comment: Do you see any error in browser console? Any custom JS added on page OR column/list validation added to list?

Comment: No Custom code or console errors.No Validation errors also :-(